# Securely use Connection string of MongoAtlas in Node.Js to connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to MongoAtlas for a local project. Is there any way of breaking down the connection string into variables like database name, database password, database hostname, etc, that has been given to me in 'Connect your Application' in the connect part(Driver settings:- Node 3.0+). Although I could use the driver example they have given to me I would like to do it with mongoose.connect(). Can anyone tell as to what should be done?

Comment: Yes since it's just a string you can split it into multiple parts & concatenate all to form a string or else you can use string literals to replace values of connection string or even better for security purposes you can encrypt & decrypt connection string upon usage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that using [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```
process.env.uName = 'username'
process.env.password = 'password'
process.env.server = 'cluster123-abcde.mongodb.net'

const uName = process.env.uName 
const password = process.env.password
const server = process.env.server

const url = `mongodb+srv://${uName}:${password}@${server}/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

**Note :** If you're using any cloud provider then they're having something like [aws-secrets-manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) or [aws-systems-manager-parameter-store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to store environment variables in a secured manner. You can get those values from here & set it up on runtime once before connection is established. Or traditionally you can find someway to populate environment variables during deployment time.

If you need it in more secured manner, then you can encrypt your complete connection string & store **encrypted string** + **key** somewhere & while connection creation decrypt those to make a connection, Check this :

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); // Take use of crypto library from Node.Js
const secretKey = 'somestringlengthof32';

function decrypt(text) {
    let res = null;
    try {
        const textParts = text.split(':');
        const iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
        const encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(':'), 'hex');
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(secretKey), iv);
        let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
        decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
        res = decrypted.toString();
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('Error in decrypt func ::', err);
    }
    return res;
}

function encrypt(text) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(secretKey), iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
    return `${iv.toString('hex')}:${encrypted.toString('hex')}`;
}

const urlString = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster123-abcde.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const encryptedString = encrypt(urlString)
console.log(encryptedString) // Store this string & secretKey somewhere in secured place & use these while connection creation by calling decrypt function
console.log(decrypt(encryptedString))
```